# Trouble setting up Go environment on OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, go

I've installed Go on OSX using Homebrew so that I could install [alpaca](https://github.com/pksunkara/alpaca#installation), but keep getting errors like this:

```
package github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice/rice
    imports github.com/GeertJohan/go.incremental
    imports github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice/embedded
    imports github.com/akavel/rsrc/binutil
    imports github.com/akavel/rsrc/coff
    imports github.com/daaku/go.zipexe
    imports github.com/jessevdk/go-flags
    imports github.com/robertkrimen/terst
    imports testing: unrecognized import path "testing"
package github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice/rice
    imports github.com/GeertJohan/go.incremental
    imports github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice/embedded
    imports github.com/akavel/rsrc/binutil
    imports github.com/akavel/rsrc/coff
    imports github.com/daaku/go.zipexe
    imports github.com/jessevdk/go-flags
    imports github.com/robertkrimen/terst
    imports bitbucket.org/kardianos/osext
    imports bitbucket.org/pkg/inflect
    imports unicode: unrecognized import path "unicode"
make: *** [deps] Error 1
```

Googling around it seems the issue is with my go environment, but I can't seem to figure out how to resolve this. Here's what I see when I run `go env`:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/mc/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/Users/mc/go/packages"
GOTOOLDIR="/Users/mc/go/packages/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: The path of GOROOT seems off. It can't be inside GOPATH, it's usually some system directory.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Do you have an example of what it should be? I installed via brew, so should it be something in `/usr/local/Cellar/go`? If so, any idea what?

Comment: Okay, got it figured out -- using `export GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.1/libexec` did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GOROOT="/Users/mc/go/packages"` is incorrect.

You should not have to set your `GOROOT`. checkout out this [blog post](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really) by Dave Cheney.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, @not_a_golfer 's comment helped me figure this out -- the GOROOT needs to be where brew installed Go.

In my case `export GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.1/libexec` resolved it.

Comment: You should not have to set your `GOROOT`. checkout out this [blog post](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really) by Dave Cheney.

Comment: @jmaloney If you put that in an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Hey @Michael I moved my comment to the answer.